# How to post user and bot activities to conversation

Tags: botframework

I have implemented bot which saves all sent and received activities to Table Storage as Activity Objects (JSON) using Conversation ID as key.

When user reconnects to the conversation I want to send all activities from Table storage using the related Conversation ID.

The problem is that activities originally send by the bot works ok but user activies are not visible in conversation. I've tested this with Botframework Emulator. No errors are triggered. 
I guess I am not creating activities correctly.

Here is my code (confJSONObj contains the previously saved activity information)

```
var confJSONObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>(logEntry.ActivityJson);

if (confJSONObj.Type.Contains("message"))
{
    IMessageActivity message2 = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
    message2.Recipient = confJSONObj.Recipient;
    message2.From = confJSONObj.From;
    message2.Conversation = confJSONObj.Conversation;
    message2.ChannelId = confJSONObj.ChannelId;
    message2.Text = confJSONObj.Text;
    message2.Speak = confJSONObj.Text;
    message2.Locale = confJSONObj.Locale;
    message2.Type = confJSONObj.Type;
    message2.Id = confJSONObj.Id;
    message2.Timestamp = confJSONObj.Timestamp;
    message2.LocalTimestamp = confJSONObj.LocalTimestamp;
    message2.ServiceUrl = confJSONObj.ServiceUrl;
    message2.TextFormat = confJSONObj.TextFormat;
    message2.ChannelData = confJSONObj.ChannelData;
    message2.Attachments = confJSONObj.Attachments;

    await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> activities originally send by the bot works ok but user activies are
>   not visible

This is because the WebChat control is not written to support re-displaying messages that originated from the user (normally, the webchat control receives user messages from the text box at the bottom of the control, not from the server).

Currently, replaying chat history in the WebChat control is not a supported feature.  This Pull Request: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/pull/615  for the WebChat control is a step in that direction: but it hasn't been merged or released yet (and, there is more work that needs to be done from the bot side in order to make this a fully functional feature).

There is a .net sdk bot here: https://github.com/JasonSowers/ChatHistoryBot-Public that uses a forked WebChat to restore history from a database.  But, this is an unsupported and unmaintained implementation.

There has been extensive discussion on what would be required to replay conversation history in WebChat here: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/issues/365  Please feel free to contribute to that discussion.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Any idea when the Issue 365 will be included to the official release of WebChat?